# Why does using a numpy array instead of a torch tensor use more memory in this example?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Using this method gives me a train_data size of about 700Mb and test of about 200Mb

```
data_tensor = torch.Tensor([np.repeat(image[...,np.newaxis],3,-1)/255.0 for image in data])

np.save(f"/home/vedank/Desktop/code/facial_sentiment/{dataset_type}_data.npy",np.array(data_tensor))
```

However, using the one below increases the size of train_data to 1.6 Gb and test to ~400Mb

```
data_tensor = np.array([np.repeat(image[...,np.newaxis],3,-1)/255.0 for image in data])

np.save(f"/home/vedank/Desktop/code/facial_sentiment/{dataset_type}_data.npy",data_tensor)
```

Comment: Check the datatypes, specially if the data is float32 or float64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the default datatype for numpy (float) arrays is 64 bits.

```
import numpy as np 
print(np.array([2.3]).dtype)
# we get float 64
```

on the other hand, [pytorch default float datatype is float32](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_default_dtype.html)

That means the size of the array in numpy should be double the one in PyTorch.